# How to make PDF.js to work with Internet Explorer 9+?

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, pdf.js

I am aware that `PDF.js` does not support `IE8` and below versions; but it does not work for `IE9+` too. Are you aware of any workarounds to make it compatible with `IE9+`?

I also imported `compatibility.js` just before `pdf.js`.

Comment: Works for me at http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html. If you are creating a custom app, please paste a link to what you have so far.

Comment: here is a demo of a PDF preview window extension for Ext JS 4 that uses pdf.js. It works as expected in all other browsers. @async5

Comment: So you are saying that's it's a problem of "PDF preview window extension for Ext JS 4" rather than PDF.js?

Comment: you did not paste a link. I found https://github.com/sunbox/st2_pdf_panel/ but this one is using really old version of PDF.js built by the author of the project.